# In Android Studio, how to use GridView to display a matrix of Text Boxes?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, matrix, gridview

I am working on a project that involves telling a user to input what size they want a matrix to be, by using a dropdown Spinner and then press submit, and then there will be a new Activity displaying a matrix of Text Boxes of the dimension(size) the user selected.

I find this task to be quite tricky, given that this is my very first Android Studio project and I am still a novice at it.

The picture below tells the user what dimension they want the matrices to have.

[image]

Here is the XML code for the Activity that will appear after the user selects a dimension:

```
       <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="368dp"
            android:layout_height="495dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:text="Please input the numbers on both matrices." />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
                android:text="Matrix1: "
                android:textStyle="bold" />

           <GridView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView11" />

       </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the code that uses the dimensions from the dropdown Spinners:

```
public void submitButton(View view)
{
    //get the dimensions
    Integer rows = (Integer) matrix1Rows.getSelectedItem();
    Integer columns = (Integer) matrix1Columns.getSelectedItem();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TwoMatricesDimensionSubmitActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

}
```

For the TwoMatricesDimensionSubmitActivity, I want it to display a GridView that displays a matrix of text boxes with a dimension size that the user selected, but I couldn't figure out how to put the values of rows and columns into the XML of the next Activity nor do I know how do use a GridView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in 5 steps

Create a Matrix object

```
public class Matrix 
{
    public int i;
    public int j;
    public Matrix(int i, int j) 
    {
        this.i = i;
        this.j = j;
    }
}
```

Create a new layout called 'griditem.xml'. This is the single representation of each item on your grid

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Create an Adapter for your Grid-View

```
public class MatricAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    List<Matrix> matrixList;

    public MatricAdapter(Context context, List<Matrix> matrixList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.matrixList = matrixList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return matrixList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return matrixList.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View v=View.inflate(context,R.layout.griditem,null);
        return v;
    }
}
```

Now On your new Activity (I assume, you got the row and column in the MatrixGrid display activity)

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // GET THE MATRIX DIMENSIONS
        int rows=4;
        int columns=3;

        // INITIALISE YOUR GRID
        GridView grid=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid);
        grid.setNumColumns(columns);

        // CREATE A LIST OF MATRIX OBJECT
        List<Matrix> matrixList=new ArrayList<>();

        // ADD SOME CONTENTS TO EACH ITEM
        for (int i=0;i<rows;i++)
        {
            for (int j=0;j<columns;j++)
            {
                matrixList.add(new Matrix(i,j));
            }
        }

        // CREATE AN ADAPTER  (MATRIX ADAPTER)
        MatricAdapter adapter=new MatricAdapter(getApplicationContext(),matrixList);

        // ATTACH THE ADAPTER TO GRID
        grid.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Now you got your NxM matrix. Hope this helps

Comment: This actually did help thanks! The only problem I'm having is knowing how to transfer the rows and columns that the user selected from the previous Activity onto the new Activity.

Comment: You can do this with Intents. On the sending activity side `Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("row", intValue);myIntent.putExtra("column", intValue);
startActivity(myIntent);` . And on the reciver activity at onCreate() methord catch the passed values like `Intent mIntent = getIntent();
 int row= mIntent.getIntExtra("row", 0); int column= mIntent.getIntExtra("column", 0);`   Hope it helps

Comment: Happy to hear that. Is this work for an answer tick?

Comment: No it's for a linear algebra calculator and I'm trying to make it so that the user creates their own matrix by setting N rows and M columns and then put the numbers in each EditText in a NxM matrix of EditTexts.

Comment: Is your problem solved? Can you set this as answer by clicking that green tick?

Comment: Ohhh okay. Sorry I'm new to this website. Yes my problem is solved